# Javascript error saving modules after upgrade to Joomla 3.2

Tags: javascript, joomla

I recently updated to Joomla 3.2. Since that time I have been unable to save new or changes to many different types of modules. Using firebug I tracked the error down to several javascript errors. Here is what I am seeing on firebug;

When creating a custom HTML module

When the new module loads I get;

TypeError: document.formvalidator is null
http://optionsprofitcycle.com/administr ... ayout=edit
Line 327

When I press any of the buttons (Save, Save & Close, Save & New, Cancel) I get;

TypeError: b is null
http://optionsprofitcycle.com/media/system/js/core.js
Line 4

When creating a jevents calendar I get similar results;

On Page Load

TypeError: document.formvalidator is null
http://optionsprofitcycle.com/administr ... ayout=edit
Line 319

When I press any of the buttons (Save, Save & Close, Save & New, Cancel) I get;

TypeError: b is null
http://optionsprofitcycle.com/media/system/js/core.js
Line 4

I tried many other modules with similar results. Yes I have flushed all the caches on the browser and in Joomla - several times. I also applied the Joomla 3.2 Update to my install as other people have suggested. The errors happen in a similar way in Firefox, Chrome and IE 9.

None of these errors were present before upgrading from 3.1.5 to 3.2. Progress on the site is basically at a standstill due to these errors.

Any help would be very appreciated. Either suggestions to fix the issue or suggestions that would help me debug this myself.

Thank you

Comment: Make sure that all of the js files that should have been deleted on the upgrade were actually deleted. CYou ca

Comment: Do you use any kind of CDN?